# evento onclick não está chamando a função

Tags: javascript, html, axios, request, electron

O evento onclick não está chamando a função desejada

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <title>
        app
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
    <input type="button" onclick="CriarLobby()"> criar lobbt </input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const { app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const axios = require('axios');
const LCUConnector = require('lcu-connector');
const connector = new LCUConnector();
const https = require('https');
const agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

function createWindow(){
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
    height: 600,
     webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

connector.on('connect', async(credentials) => {
    console.log('League Client started.');

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://127.0.0.1:${credentials.port}`,
     headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${credentials.username}:${credentials.password}`)
            .toString("base64")}`,
        },
        httpsAgent: agent
    });

function CriarLobby(){
      api.post('/lol-lobby/v2/lobby', {
      queueId: 430,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

}
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificou o console através do browse? Pode ser que outra parte do código esteja errada e não a chamada de função.

Tenta usar o this na sua chamada de função.

OBS.: A tag INPUT não precisa ser fechada.

Faz um teste apenas entre a chamada da função e o JS pra ver se realmente o problema está nela.

```
<form id="form">
    <button onclick="CriarLobby(this)"> criar lobbt </button>
</form>

<script>
 function CriarLobby(){

   alert("Função ok");
   console.log("Função ok");
 }
</script>
```

Comment: o seu código funcionou mas quando eu substitui pela minha função original (msm criando ela na tag script) a função não foi chamada, tentei até utilizar o seguinte código: `<form id="form">
    <button id="botao"> criar lobby </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(document.getElementById('botao').clicked == true)
{
      CriarLobby();

}

</script> ` mas não funcionou, acredito que o problema só pode estar na função

Comment: quanto ao console o resultado é esse: [imagem](https://prnt.sc/y3kwsx)

Comment: Já respondi hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

A resposta é simples amigo, você não consegue chamar a função porque você declarou a função **dentro** da função `createWindow`, ou seja, ela só existe dentro do escopo da função createWindow, por isso da o erro `CreateLobby não foi definido` porém isso se resolve se você declarar a função fora do escopo da função `createWindow`.